# Rephrasing “There was not enough commitment on my part or John's.”

Tags: conjunctions, negation, possessives, coordination

(migrated from https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Are the following all correct and semantically equivalent? And even if they are, which ones are preferred and why?

- There was not enough commitment on **my part or John's**.
- There was not enough commitment on **my part nor John's**.
- There was not enough commitment on **my or John's part**.
- There was not enough commitment on **mine or John's part**.
- There was not enough commitment on **mine nor John's part**.

Comment: I will repeat my previous comment: "The question ... lacks a context. I don't prefer any of them, for what little that's worth, but not having a context prevents anyone from stating a meaningful preference: sentences like this usually don't exist in isolation. Passives are usually clumsy & verbose. Both _Neither John nor I was committed enough_ & _John & I weren't committed enough_ seem better to me. Every sentence in a discourse is like a piece of a jigsaw puzzle: either it fits or it doesn't. Show us at least part of the puzzle. Then ask" a real question.

Comment: @Bill Franke: Go on, I'll bite. Suggest me two possible contexts such that you would prefer different alternatives from the above in each. I certainly can't think of any additional context that could affect how bad all of them sound to me, or make me "rank" them differently.

Comment: @Fumble: I fully agree with your "They're all clumsy phrasings...those last 5 words are just too 'busy'" & wouldn't use them unless the paragraph contained a list of reasons the project failed, but I'd have to change the syntax: "Why did the project fail? Three reasons. There wasn't enough money from A or B. There wasn't enough support from C or D. There wasn't enough commitment from E or F." Maybe those "or"s should be "and"s.

Comment: @Bill: Well, we can assume from OP's ***nor*** versions that he actually means ***and***. But I'm happy to call it *inclusive 'or'*, even though strictly speaking *or* admits of the possibility that either John ***or*** myself (but not *both*) was committed enough. But you could say the same about *and*, in this particular construction. All I know is there wasn't enough commitment, from me and/or John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're all clumsy phrasings, but for what it's worth I'd grade them (from most to least acceptable) as...

> There was not enough commitment on my part or John's.
>   There was not enough commitment on mine or John's part.
>   There was not enough commitment on my or John's part.
>   There was not enough commitment on my part nor John's.
>   There was not enough commitment on mine nor John's part.

We can throw out the *mine* versions on grammatical/idiomatic grounds by noting that Google Books has 292 instances of ["on your or our part"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on%20mine%20or%20his%20part%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22on%20your%20or%20our%20part%22&oq=%22on%20your%20or%20our%20part%22&gs_l=serp.3...15743.20124.4.20569.13.13.0.0.0.0.141.963.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.Fj-JGl4CFCw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.d2k&fp=25cc13c08eb94fcb&biw=1275&bih=922), but only 3 of ["on yours or our part"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on%20mine%20or%20his%20part%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22on%20yours%20or%20our%20part%22&oq=%22on%20yours%20or%20our%20part%22&gs_l=serp.3...15305.15305.5.15934.1.1.0.0.0.0.44.44.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.e9xfVPwhedI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.d2k&fp=25cc13c08eb94fcb&biw=1275&bih=922) *(my/mine = your/yours)*. And the *nor* versions are at least "unusual", in that *nor* usually follows *neither*, rather than *not*.

---

But however you arrange them, those last 5 words are just too "busy", trying to combine an [inclusive "or"](http://www.top-law-schools.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=125823) and two possessives (one a pronoun) associated with the same "part". It would be far better to avoid "problematic" constructions like this completely, and rephase as, say,...

> There was not enough commitment from either myself or John.

---

For reasons I can't easily put my finger on, I personally would identify John first, and myself second. Perhaps because the *last-named* person "stands out" more, and it's "bad form" to put more of the blame on someone else in such contexts. Or maybe just because I'm influenced by the fact that The Queen often says [My husband and I](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/252950.html)...

> There was not enough commitment **from either John or myself.**

Answer (score -1):

Due to the "not" at the beginning, you must use "nor" at the end; so that knocks out 3 of them.

The last one is not correct, as "mine" does not go with "part" (if John was not involved, you would not say "There was not enough commitment on mine part.").

So of the 5, "There was not enough commitment on my part nor John's." is correct.

Comment: -1 for the first sentence. From Google Books: ["**not** enough food **nor** water"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+enough+food+nor+water%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 2 instances. ["not enough food **or** water"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+enough+food+or+water%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 1400 instances.